# fatal error: C1083 cannot open include file 'zlib.h'

Tags: python-3.x, windows, zlib

I'm trying to install pybedtools on windows and got the above error. What am I missing and above all *where* should I download it to?
I found a zlib package download for windows here http://www.zlib.net/zlib1211.zip but I have no clue how to proceed from there.
Many thanks for whoever can help. There's another post on a similar question but apparently no one answered that.

Comment: [pybedtools is on pypi](https://pypi.org/project/pybedtools/). Can you just `pip install pybedtools` rather than trying to compile it yourself?

Comment: Failure because command 'python setup.py egg_info' failed with error code 1, and some FileNotFoundError. I